# Manipulating Text on VIsio Connectors

Tags: visio

When you place a connector down there is a drag-point pre-set in the middle of its length.  When you apply text to the connector (by selecting the connector and just starting to type) the text label is set to the mid-point on the connector.

When the label and the midpoint coincide, visio prioritises selection of the mid-point over the drag handle for the text.
Is there any way to force prioritisation (through simultaneous key press, for example) to the text drag handle?  In this scenario you have to contort your connector to shift the mid point (or any connector drag-point) away from the text to allow selection of the text drag handle.

thanks.

Comment: Visio have few types of connectors. One of them have control ([yellow point](https://rus-visio-blog-archive.github.io/2012/03/27/7737.4.png)), you can replace text position with remove control.

Comment: You'll have to expand on that - the connector where the text has a yellow handle is the only connector i have ever used, and the yellow handle is the issue in my original question

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a solution to this as well as I couldn't move the text on the connector.

The solution turned out to be quite simple. Change the connector type to "Right-Angle Connector". Now the label and mid-point will likely not coincide (if it does, just adjust the line). Now you can move the text and then switch back to the Straight connector!

Answer (score -1):

Try use command **Text block** for make these changes
[image: Change Text block box in MS Visio]

Comment: Doesnt address original question though... but thanks